# Observable.if not working properly

Tags: angular, ionic2, rxjs

I dont know guys but whats wrong with this?

```
this.auth.userAvailable(data.email)
    .flatMap(res => {
      return Observable.if(
        function () {
          return res.success;
        },
        Observable.fromPromise(this.auth.localStore('user_info', data)),
        Observable.throw(new Error('User exists'))
      )
    })
    .subscribe(res => {
      this.navCtrl.push(ServiceProviderBusinessInfoPage);
    }, err => {
      let error = err.json();
      this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'Error',
        message: error.message,
        buttons: ['OK']
      }).present();
    });
```

even if the `res.success` returns `false` everytime `this.auth.localStore('user_info', data)` gets fired,
also subscribe success call is not getting fired

help me with this code, I am new for rxjs

Comment: dont know but try and change it to `arrow function` as return `Observable.if(
        () => {
          return res.success;
        },`

Comment: still the same, and also it is not reaching to subscribe success call

Answer (score 2):

In your case there is not really the need for an `Observable.if`, why not use a simple `switchMap`:

```
this.auth.userAvailable(data.email)
    .switchMap(res => {
      if (res.success) {
        return Observable.fromPromise(this.auth.localStore('user_info', data));
      } else {
        return Observable.throw(new Error('User exists'));
      }
    })
    .subscribe(res => {
      this.navCtrl.push(ServiceProviderBusinessInfoPage);
    }, err => {
      let error = err.json();
      this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'Error',
        message: error.message,
        buttons: ['OK']
      }).present();
    });
```

Comment: This is the quite good solution but what if I don't have else condition? will that work the same, Again thanks :)

Comment: There is no else-_condition_ is this example. Or did you mean an else-_resolution_? In that case you can just return `Observable.never` or `Observable.empty`, which in this case should not make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with how `if` works. This was reported here: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2768

And workaround placed here: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2768#issuecomment-317877914

So applying to your example, it would be:

```
this.auth.userAvailable(data.email)
    .switchMap(res => {
      return Observable.if(
        () => res.success,
        Observable.defer(() => Observable.fromPromise(this.auth.localStore('user_info', data))),
        Observable.throw(new Error('User exists'))
      )
    })
    .subscribe(res => {
...
```